# When trimming a tree, what does the term "branch angle to the trunk" mean and, what is the ideal angle?

Tags: trees, pruning, tree-care

In [a document provided by the city of Montreal](http://espacepourlavie.ca/en/young-trees-formative-pruning) for home onwners, it states

> "Choose branches that form a wide angle (50° to 100°) to the trunk
>   which encourage them to bear fruit."

In the [French version of the same document](http://espacepourlavie.ca/jeunes-arbres-formation), it states 50° to 130°.

My understanding is that branches should stoop downward from the trunk:

```
|  <- max 130 degree
|\
| \
```

or upward:

```
|  
| /
|/
|  <- max 130 degree
```

or anything in between, including perpendicular:

```
|
|----
|
```

Is my understanding correct and is this generally what is recommended?

Comment: Personally I don't like such document. Every plant is different, and in particular fruit plants need to be pruned differently. It seems strange, but I thinkthe angles are from the upper part. (30 degree: up, nearly vertical). If you don't have weights, you get what the plant offers to you, so large angles. I would try not go much down: with leaves and fruit weight branches will go more down later.

Comment: Now I know why francophone neighborhoods look different than english ones in Montreal. ;)

Comment: I think the English version is better than French one. Those angles 100°-130°sound insane to me.